# WpDataTables conditional formatting

Tags: javascript, wordpress, datatable, formatting, conditional-statements

I'm trying to find a solution for this conditional formatting.
When the "INSTALLED" column is "YES" I wish cell "HARD DISK" turns green.
Some idea?
Thanks so much!

Example without conditional formatting:
[image: Example without conditional formatting]

Example with conditional formatting:
[image: Example with conditional formatting]

Comment: No idea for the moment...

Answer (score 0):

To get an idea how conditional formatting is implemented I suggest looking into assets/js/wpdatatables/wpdatatables.js

Basically it's not quite easy - that's a hint on what you would need to do:

Hook into either .draw() or .row() callback of the wpDataTables.table_1.api() object on the page (in an inline script or in a separate .js file):

- Check for the value of the third column (yes/no);
- Apply a CSS class for the second column based on the yes/no value (e.g. "green" or "red";
- Add CSS rules for ".green" and ".red" classes - setting the background-color to red and to green.

Answer (score 0):

A probable solution is to apply a row CSS rule if the value installed is `yes` and then a cell CSS rule if `HD` is not empty.

Then in CSS you could find an easy workaround.

```
.row-yourclass .cell-yourclass2 {
    background-color: green;
}
```